# Detect data anomalies in data pipe and trigger scheduled datapipeline

Tags: palantir-foundry

In Foundry, we have a data pipeline where we want to insert a code node (repo or workbook) that detects anomalies and then sends and email or some other alert about the problem.

Having trouble finding this in the documentation, can someone point me to it?

Ideally we would love to have the code trigger the Scheduler to do a pipeline run to create a REPORT, (maybe even Quiver, to do some timeline analysis). Is this possible? Are there examples in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation in the **Data Health** section of the platform documentation. There are a number of patterns possible, including defining data expectations in your code.

Whether defined as expectations or dataset health checks, failures can be set up to create Issues within the platform, which can have default assignees (individuals or groups) that will also send notifications, which are both in platform and over email (depending on per-user configuration).

Health check failures will also automatically populate the data health tab in the Project Catalog view, which can serve as a dashboard to view the overall health of the project. You can also surface these in the Data Lineage view with a coloring based on Data Health to understand issues across the breadth of the pipeline.

For a comprehensive approach to pipeline health, review the **Pipelines and best practices** section in the **Code Repositories** documentation.